# I can't understand why my waveform is coming out this way

Tags: vhdl

I am very new to VHDL coding and I have been trying to debug my code for a 32-bit adder/subtractor. The N-bit adder/subtractor is composed multiple 1-bit adder/subtractor using a generate statement. I have been testing it for 6-bit inputs using simulation. The waveform is constantly incorrect and I have tried changing just about everything. Maybe, it is a problem with the delays and the generate statement not cycling through correctly. (I am just beginning to learn how to code in vhdl.)

**My 1-bit adder/subtractor**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity addsub_1bit is
Port ( in_0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       in_1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
       cin : in  STD_LOGIC;
       AddOrSub : in  STD_LOGIC;
       sum_sub : out  STD_LOGIC;
       cout_bout : out  STD_LOGIC);
end addsub_1bit;

architecture data_flow_addsub_1bit of addsub_1bit is

begin

sum_sub <= (in_1 and (not in_0) and (not cin)) or ((not in_1) and in_0 and                       (not cin)) or ((not in_1) and (not in_0) and cin) or (in_1 and in_0 and cin) after 19 ns;
cout_bout <= (in_1 and in_0 and (not AddOrSub)) or ((not in_1)and in_1 and    cin) or ((not in_1)and cin and AddOrSub) or (in_0 and cin) or (in_1 and cin and AddOrSub) after 19 ns;

end data_flow_addsub_1bit;
```

**The N-bit adder/subtractor:**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

ENTITY adder_sub32 is
GENERIC (BW : INTEGER :=32);
PORT ( a_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
b_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
cin : IN STD_LOGIC;
sub : IN STD_LOGIC;
sum_32 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
cout : INOUT STD_LOGIC ;
ov : OUT STD_LOGIC ); -- ov stands for overflow
END adder_sub32 ;

ARCHITECTURE adder_sub32_arch OF adder_sub32 IS

signal tmp : std_logic_vector (BW downto 0);

BEGIN

tmp(0) <= cin;

gen: for i IN 0 TO BW-1 GENERATE
as1: entity work.addsub_1bit
    PORT MAP(
    in_0 => a_32(i),
    in_1 => b_32(i),
    cin => tmp(i),
    AddOrSub => sub,
    sum_sub => sum_32(i),
    cout_bout => tmp(i+1));

end GENERATE;

ov <= tmp(BW) after 95 ns;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

**My testbench:**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY adder_sub32_TB_SHan_53967364 IS
END adder_sub32_TB_SHan_53967364;


ARCHITECTURE behavior OF adder_sub32_TB_SHan_53967364 IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT adder_sub32 IS
    GENERIC (BW : INTEGER :=32);
    PORT ( a_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
    b_32 : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
    cin : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    sub : IN STD_LOGIC ;
    sum_32 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BW -1 downto 0);
    cout : INOUT STD_LOGIC ;
    ov : OUT STD_LOGIC ); -- ov stands for overflow
END COMPONENT;


signal a : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0); --:= (others => '0');
signal b : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0); --:= (others => '0');
signal cin  : std_logic;
signal sub  : std_logic;
signal cout : std_logic;
signal sum_32 : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
signal ov : std_logic;


BEGIN


test1: adder_sub32
    GENERIC MAP (6)
    PORT MAP (a_32 => a,b_32 => b,cin => cin,sub => sub,sum_32 => sum_32,cout => cout,ov => ov);

sub <= '0';
cin <= '0';
a <= "101010";
b <= "110101";
END;
```

**The waveform I got:**

[image: waveform]

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469062/32-bit-full-adder-subtractor-in-vhdl ? Its code looks suspiciously similar. In any case the output waveform looks exactly as I would expect so what is the problem? If you expect to see intermediate values you need to display individual delta cycles : perhaps your simulator has a "list" window capable of this? And if you don't understand  delta cycles, you have some reading to do...

Comment: This is not a duplicate, i am assuming the other post is from someone in the same class as me and the entities are identical because they cannot be modified. But thank you both either way. @BrianDrummond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final sum is correct ("101010" + "110101" = "011111") in this case, *but not in all cases.*

**EDIT2**: Let's take a closer look, why the carry is not rippling as expected in your addition. The bits 0 (LSB) to 5 of the operands together, request that the carry-in is propagated from bit 0 to the carry-in of bit 6. Bits 6 of the operands generate a carry, which is carry-out of the adder. As the `cin` of bit 0 is '0', all intermediate carry-ins will be '0' too, but it should ripple through the carry-chain.

Now lets, take a look at the one-bit adder. You are adding two numbers, so that, `AddOrSub` is '0'. With this, the equation of `cout_bout` can be simplified to:

```
cout_bout <= (in_1 and in_0) or (in_0 and cin);
```

This equation is definitly wrong, because the carry-in is not propagated when `in_1` = '1' and `in_0` = '0'. Thus, some of the intermediate carries will be computed to '0' just after 19 ns without waiting for the rippling carry. The corresponding sum bit will be valid after 38 ns as shown in your waveform. The final value of the sum is not affected because this shortcuted carry is identical to the expected rippling carry. Please consider here, that all the 1-bit adder (generated by the `generate` statement) work concurrently.

To fix the equation, I recommend to write a testbench for the 1-bit adder. This testbench would have to check all possible 16 input combinations of `in_0`, `in_1`, `cin`, and `AddOrSub`.

Another testcase would be to add the above two operands with an `cin` of '1'.
(End of EDIT2.)

---

The `ov` is correct too in this case, *but not in all cases*.

**EDIT**: You mixed up the overflow `ov` with the carry-out `cout`. The overflow flag indicates an overflow in the signed number space. For the addition, the overflow flag is '1' if and only if:

- the addition of two positive numbers results in a negative sum, or
- the addition of two negative numbers results in a positive sum.

For subtraction it is the other way round.

Because this is a homework question, I will not solve it completely. But I will give a you a testcase where your current logic fails: if you add 1 ("000001") plus -1 ("111111"), then the sum must be zero, the overflow '0' and the carry-out '1'. (End of Edit.)

---

The `cout` is 'U' because you haven't connected it in `adder_sub32`. The carry-out is the top-most bit in your carry-chain, and thus:

```
cout <= tmp(BW);
```

And you should fix the direction of `cout` in `adder_sub32`. The carry-out is just an output of this component. So declare it as `out` instead of `inout`.

Comment: Note that ov already purported reveals that same bit - `ov <= tmp(BW) after 95 ns;` and it's unknown. Making your change, adding a hold over delay to the testbench reveals that ov was in exerted when the simulation originally ended: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1QBao.png.  The INOUT mode cout is apparently part of the assignment, which has an image capture in the history of the other question Brian alludes to in his comment.

Comment: You could also postulate the ov will not be correct for all cases. An overflow occurs when both operand MSBs are the same and the result MSB is different. The carryout of the MSB isn't synonymous (as in for subtraction, which doesn't appear to work in the OP's model): http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8zfz.png

Comment: @user1155120 Yes, you are right. I just overlooked the wrong calculation of `ov`. I improved my answer.

Comment: @CASTOR I added more details about the wrong overflow calculation to my answer. Just in case my answer does not solve your question, then you must add more details about the expected results in your question.

Comment: Thank you @MartinZabel . all the feedback was so helpful and i really appreciate you not just giving me the answer cause i am really trying to learn and understand this stuff. Just to clarify, the COUT INOUT cannot be modified and does not necessarily have to be used and we can replace it with a signal of our choosing. Thanks for pointing out how my ov was not correct. As far as the waveform goes, i was wondering why my delays from my addsub_1bit were not propogating the way a ripple carry adder would but correct me if im wrong. Is it because using a GENERATE statement is concurrent?

Comment: Thank you @user1155120 for your feedback! i tried to add you in the last comment but i guess i can only reply to 1 person at a time.

Comment: @CASTOR The carry is not rippling as expected, because the computation within the 1-bit adder is broken. I have extended my answer at the beginning to explain why.

Comment: @MartinZabel wow, thank you so much. i did test all 16 cases for my 1 bit adder subtractor but I failed to notice that it was incorrect as did the grader. I really appreciate the time you spent on this post. Thank you again and i believe you have given me enough information to fix all the problems with this code.